# Helm Deployment of multiple microservices with single configmap

Tags: kubernetes-helm

we are deploying multiple microservices using helm charts but all those microservices are using one shared objects such as configmap.
Requirement should be when we do helm deployment microservices will be installed/upgraded using "helm upgrade --install", but it should not try to deploy shared configmap for all the microservice.
Shared configmap has to be deployed only once but all the microservices has to use that shared configmap, how can we achieve this with helm and what will be the helm structure and concepts for my case.

Comment: deploy the configmap first and reference it in all other charts. There are plenty of charts out there that have the option to create a configmap or use a pre existing one. You can check bitnami charts for example, they do this alot.

Answer (score 0):

Please be more specific in your question, you are deploying each of you ms separately?

Let's suppose you have 3 ms - A, B and C. If you want to use shared config map for all of those, so you have next options:

1. Create top level chart, which includes A, B and C sub charts, as well as configmap definition. This way when you deploy your TLC, config map will be created once.
2. If you need to deploy each chart independently, in this case create separate chart which includes only config map, deploy it first, and then deploy all A, B and C charts.

Upd.

Example of how you can perform lookup and check if resource exists, and based on this create or not create.

```
{{- $secretName:= (tpl .Values.your.secret.secretName .)}}
{{- $secret:= (lookup "v1" "Secret" .Release.Namespace $secretName)}}
{{- if not $secret}}
{{- $defUsername:= (b64enc "test")}}
{{- $defPassword:= (b64enc "test")}}
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: "{{$secretName}}"
  namespace: "{{.Release.Namespace}}"
type: Opaque
data:
  username: {{$defUsername}}
  password: {{$defPassword}}
{{- end}}
```

Comment: I'm deploying all the ms separately, all ms should use same configmap. It should not try to creates for individual deployment.

Comment: The standard mechanism of using secrets and config maps IMO is include configmap definition in each chart, and add option to populate name of existing configmap externally.

In this case you could deploy charts independently, in case if configmap already exist - just populate its name. If name is not populated - this specific MS will create config map.

Comment: You could even use lookup function in order to check if config map exists, and based on result create or not create config map.

Comment: Hi, How can I do this... include configmap definition in each chart, and add option to populate name of existing configmap externally.
can u share me any details on this.

Comment: Updated initial answer, you can look on how it is done in case of 'secret'

Comment: Hi I understood that, but got one more doubt by looking at it. If we have some updates in that secret file, by following above one if the secret is there with that name it will just bypass the installation it wont update it. How can I overcome that.

Comment: If configmap was created externally (manually or created by ms A), then for ms B it is only a prerequisite. 

Overall it is not the best approach. IMO, Deploy all charts together in on TLC. Or if you want deploy separately, then include configmap definition to each subchart. 

There is no reason to use "shared" configmap if you are not planning to deploy those charts together... 

And vise versa if you do plan to deploy it separately it means it should be self deployable meaning include its own configmap definition (with unique name).

Or just deploy config map as a separate chart...